# setting hidden form "value" doesn't stick with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which passes in a jQuery object called "targetElement" which is the form field that I need to operate on. I use this function to set default values for a form after it loads. In one form I have three hidden form elements (aka, `<input type="hidden">`) each one is assigned a value and two of the three work fine. The third is driving me nuts.

Here's a code snippet within the function:

```
case "today":
    SetFieldValue (targetElement , Date.today().toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") );
    console.log ('Setting ' + jQuery(targetElement).attr('id') + ' to "today": ' + Date.today().toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") );
    break;
```

Where the SetFieldValue function is:

```
function SetFieldValue ( domObject, value ) {
  // as a safety function, check if a string representation of the domObject was passed in and convert it to a jQuery object if it was
  if ( jQuery.type(domObject) === "string") {
    domObject = jQuery(domObject);
  }

  if ( jQuery.inArray (domObject.prop('tagName').toLowerCase(),['input' , 'select' , 'textarea']) >= 0 ) {
    console.log ("setting to value attribute: " + value);
    domObject.attr('value',value);
    console.log ("now set to: " + domObject.attr('value') + "(" + domObject.attr('id') + ")" );
  } else {
    console.log ("setting to html attribute");
    domObject.html( value );
  }
  return domObject;
}
```

Here's the thing. I set a debug breakpoint directly after the call to SetFieldValue. I typed "targetElement" which clearly shows that the value HAS been set.  Yet, when I type a jQuery reference to the DOM field it shows up without the value set. Huh?

[image]

Now there is one thing I didn't mention ... and I suspect it's important ... when I typed "targetObject" into the debugger the first thing it did was return an empty array:

[image]

Then a second or two later it expanded auto-magically into the screen shot you saw initially. Please help!

### UPDATE

I really appreciate all the help so far but I suspect the real problem is hinted at by the "delay" in response to targetElement (a jQuery object). See above for more details. I have also added another interesting snapshot below. If you notice the log.console statements in the code this will make sense:

[image]

What I have attempted to do is:

a) state what I'm going to set the value to
b) set the value to stated intention (aka, 2012-12-02 00:00:00)
c) check that it has been set (it has)
d) then check again from the calling routing (this also confirms it has been set)

On the line immediately following the last log.console (the "break" statement) I put a breakpoint and the debugger no disagrees with all the console messages. Bizzarre!

### *UPDATE 2*

People have asked for additional context, well "code" to be precise. I am struggling to figure out a good way to give a compact module of code that will reproduce the problem so I thought maybe a short screencast demonstrating the problem would help. Here's two attempts at that:

[screencast 1](https://vimeo.com/54816768)
[screencast 2](https://vimeo.com/54818500)

Comment: What is the domObject actually referring to? It needs to be an input element of some form (textarea included) to be able to set the value post HTML 4.0

Comment: it is an input element (see above). In fact that is the whole point of the SetValueField function ... to set the value in an appropriate way for the DOM element. In any event, in this case it's just html input element.

Comment: So, you're passing a DOM input element to your function, and then using jQuery methods on it? That could be your problem right there.

Comment: No it's a jQuery object passed in. Sorry I made the mistake of using them synonymously when of course they're not.

Comment: If you could reproduce the problem at http://jsfiddle.net it would help us analyze the issue.

Comment: @Blazemonger, I'd like to but I don't know how to. This should be a very simple exercise yet somehow it's failing. I'm quite sure if I put this onto jsfiddle it would work. ;^)

Comment: Then you need to give us more code, at the very least. The problem may be rooted elsewhere.

Comment: Are you creating targetElement based on a return from some ajax call?

Comment: @kinakuta not directly an AJAX call. There is an AJAX call which loads the form and on it's completion it fires a jQuery event on all the form elements that have been tagged with a "default rule" this is where the script you've seen is called.

Comment: @Blazemonger I understand that it would be good to give more visibility but I'm struggling to identify how to do it. I'm really hoping that someone's seen the pattern I've mentioned above where the debugger gives an empty set answer and then replaces it several seconds later with "the right answer". What could possibly create this condition? If I had something to go on there I think I might get closer to an answer.

Comment: The delay you describe sounds like ajax to me.

Comment: I don't think it can be. The form is already fully loaded before anything kicks off (the AJAX call just loads the HTML form elements), several DOM elements are already set to their default values (not suffering from the problem I mentioned), and then I hit my breakpoint and test from the debugger. I'll think about this some more but I just can't imagine that that is the issue right now but as I say I'll think it over again.

Comment: To me the two unexplainable problems are the time-delay and how a DOM element can be set (as indicated by console.log entry) and then in the next line of execution no longer be set to the value (using the same exact command but from the debugger). :^(

Comment: Maybe I can create a screencast ... would that help @kinakuta @Blazemonger?

Comment: I have created two screencasts that demonstrate the problem. Hopefully this provides enough context that you might be able to help. Thanks either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I didn't provide enough context for people to really dig into this problem but I have in the end solved it. What was the issue? It was silly really ... isn't it always? Anyway it was just a case of the DOM element in questions 'id' not beging unique. Grrr. It's always the obvious things that you then go onto overlook that get you in trouble.

Anyway, thanks for your patience and help.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting the value attribute through jQuery, just reference the value property of the element directly:

```
domObject[0].value = value;
```

or, don't even wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
domObject.value = value;
```

Comment: The problem I'm experiencing almost surely is related to the delay I'm getting from response in the debugger. That must be indicative of something. I'm now seeing it somewhere else and in both cases with this field. Any ideas on why this delayed response (several seconds) might be coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val) instead of `.attr('value',value)`